# How do I create objects during a data migration?

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

I'm trying to create a new object during a data migration. As far as I can tell I should use `orm.Object()` to create the new object, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for o in orm['app.Objects'].objects.all():
        ...
        n = orm.NewObject()
        n.date = datetime.date.today()
        n.object = o
        n.save()
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'
```

when I run the migration, suggesting that `n` is not being created properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I usually create these as:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for obj in orm['my_app.ModelName'].objects.all():
        orm.SomeOtherModel.objects.create(some_property=obj.some_property)
```